# Angular Isolated Scope is not working in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML Code

```
<grid-table table-rows="educationBoards"></grid-table>
```

Angular Controller

```
angular.controller('gridController', function($scope){
   $scope.educationBoards = [{eid = 1, ename = "dhaka"}];
})
```

Angular Directive

```
angular.directive('gridTable', functions(){
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {rows: '=tableRows'};
   link: function(scope){
     console.log(scope.rows); // shows undefined
   }
})
```

Directive isolated scope not working in link function. Why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of issues going on here.

First, your object in the controller is misdefined:

```
$scope.educationBoards = [{eid = 1, ename = "dhaka"}];
```

should be :

```
$scope.educationBoards = [{eid : 1, ename : "dhaka"}];
```

Second, your function is misdefined:

```
angular.directive('gridTable', functions(){
```

should be :

```
angular.directive('gridTable', function(){
```

Third, you have a semi-colon instead of comma in the middle of the directive object:

```
   scope: {rows: '=tableRows'}:
```

should be:

```
   scope: {rows: '=tableRows'},
```

Fourth, you need to *return* the object from the directive, so:

```
angular.directive('gridTable', functions(){
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {rows: '=tableRows'};
   link: function(scope){
     console.log(scope.rows); // shows undefined
   }
})
```

should be:

```
angular.directive('gridTable', function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {rows: '=tableRows'},
     link: function(scope){
       console.log(scope.rows);
     }
   };
})
```

And now it will work. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkkfqkaz/

Comment: i see it works at fiddle. But it not works in my directive. Here is github link: https://github.com/MahediSabuj/University/blob/master/Application/University.Web/Scripts/Application/Directives/GridTable.js

Comment: See if you can isolate where it is losing it.